# кастомный selectBox

Tags: javascript, select

Делаю кастомный редактируемый `<select>`.
Прописал стили, прописал дивы, осталось описать поведение. Ну и, кажется, что все просто, НО... обрабатываю клик по `input`, чтобы выводил dropdown-список.

Чтобы скрыть его, делаю так:

```
var selectElement1 = $('#selectInput1');
selectElement1.click(function() {
    $('#SelectDropdown1').show();
});
$('#1').click(function() {
    selectElement1.text('1');
});
selectElement1.blur(function() {
    $('#SelectDropdown1').hide();
});
```

Все ок, выпадающий список выпадает, жму в любой части экрана он пропадает.
Нужно теперь сделать возможность выбора значения из списка... и вот здесь проблема. Я пытаюсь обработать клик по элементу, но ничего не происходит, просто список сворачивается и все. Похоже, что срабатывает блур... Так вот, как можно это дело оформить? Причем список этот будет в итоге браться из БД. Т.е. присвоить им `id` и потом обрабатывать клик по ид не выйдет.

Форма:

```
<div class="jq-selectbox jqselect">
   <input id="selectInput1" class="form-control"></input>
   <div id="SelectDropdown1" class="jq-selectbox__dropdown" style="position: absolute; display:none">
      <ul style="position: relative; list-style: none; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
         <li onclick="SelectOpen()">1</li>
         <li id="1">2</li>
         <li>3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: php тут причем?

Comment: @Naumov, содержательный ответ, спасибо

Comment: не знаю как на счет пхп а так: https://jsfiddle.net/69ngwoz8/

Comment: @CostaRaf, все то хорошо, но при этом в инпут ничего нельзя ввести...

Comment: @АнтонБурак "Нужно теперь сделать возможность выбора значения из списка.." ничего не говорилось, про автокомплит...

Comment: @CostaRaf, автокомплит не нужен мне, но и инпут там не просто так стоит... мне нужен просто редактируемый селектбокс. т.е. чтобы можно было либо выбрать значение, либо вписать руками

Comment: Все, разобрался, большое спасибо